# Adding CSV file with lat/long to map in different CRS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

I'm very new to QGIS, so I'm sure the solution to this is common sense.

I have a map in the WGS 84 zone 58S CRS and am trying to add lat/long coordinates from a text file to it. The issue: the WGS 84 58S CRS uses meters as its reference, but my coordinates are, like I said, lat/long. This is causing my points to show up in the wrong place. If I load the text file in a different CRS (WGS 84), they show up in the right place, but then the data is in a different CRS, which is no good.

How do I take lat/long data in a text file and import it into my maps CRS, and have the data points show up in the correct locations on the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reproject your data:

1. load your text file with EPSG:4326 as CRS
2. Right click on that layer and choose "Export --> Save features as..."
3. Choose the CRS you want your data to be in (WGS 84 58S)
4. Save it (choose a file format you like)
5. Add this new file to your project

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you!